# Register opencover with typemock isolater 7.1

Tags: typemock, opencover, typemock-isolator

I have installed Typemock Isolater 7.1 and OpenCover 4.5 installed on my development machine.

When I go into TypeMock configuration and list the installed profilers Opencover does not appear.

What do I need to configure to get Typemock to recognise the presence of opencover as a linked profiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps required to use OpenCover with Typemock.

In a command prompt window with administrator access execute the following command, of course changing the PATHTOOPENCOVER to your installation directory for OpenCover.

```
regsvr32 "%PATHTOOPENCOVER%\x64\OpenCover.Profiler.dll"
```

Open the Isolator Configuration program found under Typemock\Isolater on the All Programs menu.  This must be started with Administrator access.

Check the "Show only available profilers" checkbox

Select OpenCover from the list (if it is not showing in the list the first step has not been performed.

Click on the "Link with Typemock Isolater" button.

All should work well then.